# SSL error on Chrome, IE, Safari (but not on FF)

Tags: google-chrome, internet-explorer, anti-virus, ssl-certificate, spyware

I am getting this error on trying to access a couple of sites from Chrome - one is the webmail of our company and another is a banking website.

> Cannot connect to the real somesite.com
>   Something is currently interfering with your secure connection to somesite.com.

Similar errors are seen on IE and Safari (on Windows). However, sites can be opened in Firefox which is because I believe FF has got its own mechanism to validate certificates.

The webmail is also configured in Outlook 2007 and I am not able log in to that either.

BUT on another PC that I have got, everything works normal - no errors are seen on any browser for these sites and I can access Outlook as well.

Is this because of some infection (malware/spyware/virus) on my 1st PC, perhaps? I scanned the PC using AVG antivirus and Malwarebytes but no threats were found. Both computers are running on Win 7 64 bit with latest browser versions.

Comment: Chrome had built in protection to refuse some connections without a valid certificate however chrome use the same certificate store so IE would report the same problem.  Specific information required to help.  Since Safari and IE report the same errors the certificate is actually invalid Firefox uses it's own Cert store

Comment: @Ramhound - But as I have mentioned I don't get these errors on my 2nd computer. If it's the issue with certificates shouldn't I get those errors on other machines as well?

Comment: So?  Your certificate stores are clearly not exactly the same.  Both machines running the same version of Windows?  You should be concerned if the certificate is suppose to be trusted, and its being reported as being invalid, it means the actual certificate in the store isn't trusted

Comment: @Ramhound - Okay. So what specifics do you need to help me further? What are the possible ways to fix this?

Comment: These self-signed certificates?

Comment: @Ramhound - Today the SSL warning went away automatically without me doing anything. Thanks anyways!

Comment: Sounds like your clock might have been wrong browsers behave differently with different types of errors

Comment: All the surfing I did yesterday to solve this problem first asked to check the system clock. But my system clock was never showing incorrect date and time. Not sure what went wrong yesterday and then started working today on its own!